# How to define a Python dict with more than one sub-dict having the same values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a Python `dict` whose members are themselves `dict`s, and two of them are the same:

```
servers = {
  "test": {
    "auth_token": "some-auth-token",
    "client_id": "some-client-id",
    "client_secret": "some-client-secret",
    "scope": "some-scope"
  },
  "live": {
    "auth_token": "auth-token-for-live",
    "client_id": "client-id-for-live",
    "client_secret": "client-secret-for-live",
    "scope": "scope-for-live"
  },
  "demo": servers["test"] # this doesn't work, but this is what I need
}
```

My `demo` server definition is the same as my `test` server definition, but I don't want to have to repeat it -- is there a way I can do this?

Comment: not possible in a single statement

Comment: Let's make some changes to my demo config => `servers['demo']['client_secret'] = 'foo'` => incoming stack overflow question 'My test server suddenly fails without changes, why ?' I really don't see copy-paste as a bad thing here.

Comment: can you first create dict with test and live keys. Then afterwards just update dict with demo as key and test as value ex : `servers.update({'demo':servers['test']})`

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {
    "auth_token": "some-auth-token",
    "client_id": "some-client-id",
    "client_secret": "some-client-secret",
    "scope": "some-scope"
}

servers = {
  "test": x,

  "live": {
    "auth_token": "auth-token-for-live",
    "client_id": "client-id-for-live",
    "client_secret": "client-secret-for-live",
    "scope": "scope-for-live"
  },

  "demo": x

}
```

e.g. https://repl.it/GO6Y/0

Comment: Yes, of course I can do that; I was wondering if there's a way I can do so within the definition of `servers` itself.

Comment: "How do I do X?"  "like this"  "well of course like that, I was actually asking a different question but keeping it secret because reasons"

Answer (score 0):

```
servers = {
  "test": {
    "auth_token": "some-auth-token",
    "client_id": "some-client-id",
    "client_secret": "some-client-secret",
    "scope": "some-scope"
  },
  "live": {
    "auth_token": "auth-token-for-live",
    "client_id": "client-id-for-live",
    "client_secret": "client-secret-for-live",
    "scope": "scope-for-live"
  }}

servers['demo'] = servers['test']
```

Comment: Note that changes to "test" automatically update "demo" and vice versa.